# navigate between two UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have two **UINavigationController**.
The second UINavigationController is segue from the first one.

**How do I go back to the initial View.**

Below is the storyboard.

note: The root view of the initial NavigationController is has a container from which is am performing segue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func dismissView(){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```